# Splitting comma separated values into array from optgroup - javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have some code like this:

```
var optgroup = $('#myselect').val();
var optarray = optgroup.split(',');
alert(optarray.join("\n"));
```

The first line returns something along the lines of "option1,option2,option3" if all three options are selected.  I want it to return a separate result for each option.  I have tried the above code but I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm not sure what the error is about, any help would be appreciated.  As a side note, when these values are separated, I'm going to cycle through the array and store each option on a different row of a table in SQLite.

Comment: which is the result if you log the value of optgroup with `console.log(optgroup)` ?

Comment: Exactly the same error as above

Comment: Oh my mistake, I thought you meant console.log(optarray) rather than optgroup.  console.log(optgroup) correctly shows the values option1 and option2 separated by a newline (if I don't include the split line).  myselect is the jquery mobile style select that I use for selecting the options from the optgroup.  It is just the split() that is not working

Comment: you are shure that the optgroup variable is one string?

Comment: Well when I alert that on its own it comes up as option1,option2,option3 etc...I presume that is a string

Comment: check it with `console.log(typeof optgroup);`

Comment: This is the problem, you try to use the `split` method that is for strings, but you have an `object`

Comment: Is there a workaround to this?  Are strings not classed as objects in javaScript?

Comment: Ah I just did this var optgroup = String($('#myselect').val()); and it now shows of type string and it works.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: another way to have the list of the possibility is the one that I have written in the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the list of possible selections you can use the following code:

```
var list = '';

$('#myselect option').each(function(){
  list = list + $(this).val() + '\n';
});

console.log(list);
```